# Prolog - New to Prolog, having a hard time understanding a code piece

Tags: string, recursion, prolog, increment

I have just begun learning Prolog and I found a bit of code that I have a hard time understanding:

```
stringCounter([],0,0).
stringCounter([H|[]],1,1) :- char_type(H, alpha),!.
stringCounter([H1,H2|T],CCount,WCount):-
        char_type(H1, alpha),
        \+char_type(H2,alpha),
        !,
        stringCounter(T,L0,A0),
        CCount is L0+1, WCount is A0+1.

stringCounter([H|T],CCount,WCount):-
        char_type(H, alpha),
        !,
        stringCounter(T,L1,A1),
        CCount is L1+1, WCount is A1+0.

stringCounter([_|T],CCount,WCount):- !, stringCounter(T,CCount,WCount).
```

The functions task is to calculate how many Characters there are in a string and how many words there are (as far as I have understood).

I understand most of the code here except for 3 little things:

1. How is `CCount is L0+1, WCount is A0+1` etc a valid syntax? `L0` and `A0` are completely undefined. How does Prolog know what for example `A0+1` is? Shouldn't it be `A0 is WCount + 1`?
2. I don't understand exactly what the purpose of `stringCounter([H|[]],1,1) :- char_type(H, alpha),!.` and `stringCounter([_|T],CCount,WCount):- !, stringCounter(T,CCount,WCount).` is.
3. Why does the result of the function change if I move the `stringCounter([_|T],CCount,WCount):- !, stringCounter(T,CCount,WCount).` away from the bottom (upwards)? I tried it and I got a completely different result after I moved that line.

Sorry for the very basic/silly questions but I am having a really hard time wrapping my head around Prolog and Logical Programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The functions task is to calculate how many Characters there are in a string and how many words there are (as far as I have understood).

No `CCount` (the second parameter) unifies with the number of `alpha` characters, and `WCount` unifies with the number of sequences of `alpha` characters. Soo `'foo8bar_qux'` unifies with `CCount=9` and `WCount=3`.

> How is `CCount is L0+1`, `WCount is A0+1` etc a valid syntax? **`L0` and `A0` are completely undefined**. (..)

Are they? One line above that line, we see:

```
stringCounter(T,L0,A0),
```

so it is up to `stringCounter` to ground `L0` and `A0`. If it is an invariant that `L0` and `A0` are grounded after the `stringCounter/3` call, then it will work fine. You are correct that Prolog can not handle ungrounded variables with the `is/2` predicate.

> I don't understand exactly what the purpose of `stringCounter([H|[]],1,1) :- char_type(H, alpha),!.` and `stringCounter([_|T],CCount,WCount):- !, stringCounter(T,CCount,WCount).` is.

`[H|[]]` is a verbose form of `[H]`: a list with one element `[H]`. Here we thus check if `H` is an alpha-character. If it is, then we count it as one (both for `CCount` and `WCount`). Note that it ends with a *cut* (`!`). This means that the other clauses are ignored.

The statement `stringCounter([_|T],CCount,WCount):- !, stringCounter(T,CCount,WCount).` is the last one. Since other clauses use a cut, it means that this clause is only triggered in case the list contains at least one element, and that element is not an `alpha` one. In that case, we make a recursive call on the tail, and do not count the character (for bouth `CCount` and `WCount`.

> Why does the result of the function change if I move the `stringCounter([_|T],CCount,WCount) :- !, stringCounter(T,CCount,WCount).` away from the bottom (upwards)? I tried it and I got a completely different result after I moved that line.

Because as said before, the `stringCounter([_|T],CCount,WCount)` head matches with every non-empty list. It is only because of the cuts in clauses above that one, that it is implicitly guarded to only accept non-alpha chars, etc.

So in case you moved it to the top. It will probably result in all strings having `CCount=0` and `WCount=0`, since it will recursively enumerate over the string until it reaches the end, in which case it will unify with the basecase `stringCounter([],0,0)`. Cut's can make a program more efficient, but they make the program less easy to understand due to the fact that the specifications of one clause have impact on clauses below that clause.